# Determining language from a grammar

Tags: computer-science, automata, formal-languages

I'm trying to solve an exercise on grammars and languages. Here is the exercise:

Let the grammar G be:

```
G = {V, T, P, S}, 
V = {S, A, B}, 
T = {a, b, c},

P = {S → ABA; A → a | bb; B → bS | ε}
```

What language is generated by this grammar?

I've tried to derive every possible words accepted by this grammar, but I just can't seem to find a pattern. Anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the original grammar:

```
S → ABA
A → a | bb
B → bS | ε
```

We can substitute for A and B so S is all that's left:

```
S → (a + bb)(bS + ε)(a + bb)
```

Distributing and rearranging a bit:

```
S → (a + bb)bS(a + bb) + (a + bb)(a + bb)
```

It can be shown that

```
X → rXs + t
iff
X → (r^n)t(s^n)
```

In our case:

```
S → (ab + bbb)^n (a + bb)^2 (a + bb)^n
```

I am not sure there is a super satisfying English language description of these strings, but maybe it gives a more inuitive representation than the grammar does? To each his own.